# JS Смена текста в кнопке - 2

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

Здравствуйте!

Возникает проблема при нажатии на кнопку "Показать всё", она может менять название, а может не менять но при этом по любому откроет аккордеон.

В чём может быть проблема?

(Если же я оставлю один вариант JQuery (не slim) то фреймворк Bootstrap начинает вести себя неадекватно.)

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn > span');
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  btn.innerHTML =
    (btn.innerHTML === 'Показать всё') ? btn.innerHTML = 'Скрыть' : btn.innerHTML = 'Показать всё';
})
```

```css
.card-card {
  border: 1px solid #d3d9de;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.16), 0 2px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.12);
}

.card-t {
  border-top: 1px solid #d3d9de;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.card-h {
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.buttons {
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

.card-h img {
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
</head>

<div class="container-fluid content-card">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="images/diagnostics.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Диагностика</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#diagnostics">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>




       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="images/fan.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Чистка</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#cleaning">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>




       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="images/screen.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Замена матрицы</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#screen">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>





       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
           <img src="images/hinges.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Ремонт петель</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hinges">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>







       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
           <img src="images/windows.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Установка Windows</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#install">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>





       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
           <img src="images/hdd.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Восстановление данных</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#recovery">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>





       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
           <img src="images/power.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Ремонт блока питания</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#power">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>






       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="images/hdd-replace.png">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">Замена жёсткого диска</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#hdd">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>




     <div class="container-fluid content-card2 collapse" id="services">
      <div class="row">
       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">-</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>




       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">-</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>





       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">-</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>




       <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="card-card">
         <div class="card-h" align="center">
          <img src="">
         </div>
         <div class="card-t">
          <p align="center" style="font-size: 17px; font-weight: 600;">-</p>
          <div class="buttons" align="center">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success">Подробнее</button>
          </div>
         </div>
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>


     
    <div class="container">
     <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12" align="center" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; padding-bottom: 30px;">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-success" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#services" style="margin-top: 15px;" id="show"><span>Показать всё</span></button>
     </div>
    </div>



<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Сейчас у Вас на сайте проблема из-за того, что кнопка меняет текст только по нажатию на `span` который внутри самой кнопки. Вы можете не попасть на 
`<span>Показать всё</span>` и спойлер откроется, но текст не поменяется.

*(На картинке красной линией указано место, на которое при клике текст не поменяется)*.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

По-этому стоит заменить `.btn > span` на `#show`. *(show - id кнопки)*.

```
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn > span');
const btn = document.querySelector('#show');
```

Comment: Пробовал ваш вариант, возник тот же трабл.

Второе ваше решение с правкой второго варианта на #show изменило на корню, кнопка стала работать стабильно. :D

Спасибо!

Comment: @dragunov_m, рад помочь :)

Comment: Если там тег button, то для вложенных элементов обработчики будут вызываться только в хроме.